# Visual Studio 2012 - Code Review - Remove diagonal slashes from unmatched lines

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-code-review

My team has recently converted to Visual Studio 2012 and is using the Code Review work items. When reviewing a new file, or one with substantial changes, the slashes or hashing shown for the unmatched lines causes my eyes to cross and lose focus making the review physically painful.

Is there any way to change the slashes or hashing in the Code Review tool to be something different such as a 50% grey, or at least lower the contrast of the lines so I can use the tool?

[image: Code Review usability issue depiction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it.  Not that I could find in any case.  If you want this you can let the team know by adding a suggestion to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: I was hoping a better solution would come along, but alas it has not. Added suggestion at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3314223-change-the-unmatched-line-pattern-in-visual-studio